# Display only value in one line (Comma Separated) from looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react and I've got a problem displaying the only values in JSX. An array of objects is shown below.

```
const productData=[{"label":"Name","value":"Printer"},{"label":"Name","value":"Mouse"}]
```

I am trying to display product name with below code but its not displaying anything on page:

```
{productData.map((prodData) => (
<div>
 <h2>
  Product:
  {' '}
  {prodData.value}
 </h2>
</div>
))}
```

im not sure what I am doing wrong, I want to display like:

```
Printer, Mouse
```

Comment: why you don't just create the string using js and inject it in your jsx ?
{productData.map((prodData) => prodData.value).join(', ')}

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-2bqohh . I hope this is your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you want to do :

```js
<div>
 <h2>
  Product:
  {productData.map(prodData => prodData.value).join(', ')}
 </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code each iteration is creating a new div and nested dom. Rather you will like to loop over productData inside the h2 and display each of the value in a span

```js
<div>
 <h2>
  Product:
  {productData.map((prodData) => (<span>{prodData.value}</span>))}
 </h2>
</div>
```